# Better way to handle REST calls in pyspark with json schema

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

Possibly a very easy question but I'm having a difficult time finding examples. I have a PySpark script we are using to do various enriching tasks from rest APIs (geocoding addresses, IP address lookups, etc.). Each API returns JSON as the package. Currently I have the following which doesn't seem very efficient...

To add IP address details I have the UDF:

```
def GeoCodeIP(ip):
  response = requests.get("http://ipinfo.io/"+ip+'/json')
  x = json.dumps(response.json()) #["org"]
  return x
GeoCodeIP = udf(GeoCodeIP, StringType())
```

To Geocode addresses I have

```
def GeoCodeAddress(address):
    g = geocoder.google(address, key=api_key,  exactly_one=True)
    x = g.raw #['place_id'] #json.dumps(response.json()) #["org"]
    return x
GeoCodeAddress = udf(GeoCodeAddress, StringType())
```

Both of these are adding columns to the df as

```
address_df = address_df.withColumn("PlaceID", GeoCodeAddress(address_df["address"])).collect()
```

Since I am trying to create a JSON column I then need to use another udf to load the string as JSON (this function I found in an example from Databricks)

```
schema = StructType([StructField("city", StringType()),\
                     StructField("country", StringType()),\
                     StructField("hostname", StringType()),\
                     StructField("ip", StringType()),\
                     StructField("loc", StringType()),\
                     StructField("org", StringType()),\
                     StructField("phone", StringType()),\
                     StructField("postal", StringType()),\
                     StructField("region", StringType())])
json_load = func.udf(json.loads, schema)
```

Then I add another column that is JSON type and convert to JSON (in the actual script I do the API call and json_load in the same step)

```
ip_df_w_url = ip_df_w_url.withColumn("EnrichedIP",json_load(GeoCodeIP(ip_df_w_url["ip"])))
```

The issue I am having is that since both APIs return different json how do I create a general function "json_load" that can accept a schema argument as well? Like:

```
ip_df_w_url = ip_df_w_url.withColumn("EnrichedIP",json_load(schema, GeoCodeIP(ip_df_w_url["ip"])))
```